# AMPscript Salesforce functions allow save for duplicates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm using Marketing Cloud in combination with Sales Cloud via Marketing Cloud Connect.

In one process, I'm using AMPscript Salesfroce functions to create or update records in Sales Cloud.

- [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm)
- [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm)

If duplication rule in Salesforce is triggered, I'm getting an error like this:

```
Call to create the salesforceobject Account failed! Error status code: DUPLICATES_DETECTED\nError message: Use one of these records?","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: Call to create the salesforceobject Account failed! Error status code: DUPLICATES_DETECTED\nError message: Use one of these records?\r\n  Error Code: CREATESFOJBECT_FUNC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint\r\n\r\n
```

If using Salesforce API it is possible to bypass this and allow saving of records anyway with [dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm)

Is there any chance to allow saving when using one of those AMPscript functions?

Comment: Can you bypass the rule for the Marketing Cloud admin user, the one involved inn MC Connect? So that when this user creates the record in Salesforce , this rule gets bypassed. We did this for Lead Assignment Rules, so that they did not get triggered when the lead was created by SFMC. This change needs to be implemented on the Sales cloud end.

Comment: As @SwatiMishra said you can exclude them under duplicate rules condition like if the profile is 'System admin' or user is 'MC connect' then it will exclude. Or the other way is , check if the record is already present using 'RetrieveSalesforceObject' ampscript function. If its not present then insert a record.